# Whats this exception?

Tags: java, android, exception

I have an activity (BookMarks) that is called from main activity. BookMarks throw an exception (not all the time) I can't figure out what this exception means.

```
I/ActivityManager(  181): START {cmp=com.unreal.muslim/.BookMarks} from pid 25558
I/WindowManager(  181): createSurface Window{41fbf070 Loading...  paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
I/WindowManager(  181): createSurface Window{41da2230 com.unreal.muslim/com.unreal.muslim.BookMarks paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
E/bm run catch(25558): Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
D/AndroidRuntime(25558): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(25558): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a5d1f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(25558): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.getScrapView(AbsListView.java:5900)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2003)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2072)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1044)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(25558):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  181):   Force finishing activity com.unreal.muslim/.BookMarks
W/ActivityManager(  181):   Force finishing activity com.unreal.muslim/.main
```

Can anyone help me understand this exception and a possible solution to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is your problem

```
E/bm run catch(25558): Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Where are you setting your Adapter for your ListView? Also, could you post code from your Activity?

Comment: I am updating original message with code. Also I am updating LV in handler

Comment: Never mind...while updating this post, I realized I didn't comment out code in run() for updating LV...apologies

Comment: Happens to the best of us, glad you got it. Cheers