# Error in AsyncTask update of view

Tags: android, android-view

I am getting from time to time testing my app error:

```
03-04 20:57:01.929: E/TestApp(13673): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

From questions like this: [Whats this exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685575/whats-this-exception), and my own experience (I got this same error from time to time as in mentioned question) I would like to ask you guys **what I can do to get rid of it?**

As far as I know, I can do some stuff on AsyncTask connected to View, so I don't know why I am getting this info.

*This is my code:*

```
private MyDBAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
    private ListView wordList;
private AsyncDBDownload asycn;
    private ProgressDialog dbUpdate;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.smart_guide_ocr);

            asycn = new AsyncDBDownload();

            wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordsList);
    //...
    }

    @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            asycn.execute(null);
        }

    private class AsyncDBDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    refreshList();//upload of contetn and set of adapter
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                dbUpdate.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                dbUpdate = ProgressDialog.show(TestAppActivity.this, "Wait",
                        "DB download");
            }
        }

    private void refreshList() {
            mySQLiteAdapter = new MyDBAdapter(TestAppActivity.this);
            mySQLiteAdapter.open();
            String[] columns = { MyDBAdapter.KEY_TRANSLATED, MyDBAdapter.KEY_WORD, MyDBAdapter.KEY_LANG,
                    MyDBAdapter.KEY_ID };
            Cursor contentRead = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllEntries(false, columns,
                    null, null, null, null, MyDBAdapter.KEY_ID, null);
            startManagingCursor(contentRead);
            Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(contentRead.getCount()));
            RowItem adapterCursor = new RowItem(this, R.layout.save_word_row,
                    contentRead, columns, new int[] { R.id.translatedWord, R.id.orgWord, R.id.langInfo }, 0);

            wordList.setAdapter(adapterCursor);
            mySQLiteAdapter.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not call `wordList.setAdapter(adapterCursor);` from within `refresList` method. That's a way of "changing a view from a non-UI thread".

So, instead, save the adapterCursor instance and use it from within the onPostExecute method.

Comment: As usual, great answer. Thank you Cristian.

Answer (score 0):

You can not manipulate your Views within a background task. Do all the loading you need in your AsyncTask, pass it back into the activity in onPostExecute and set your adapter then. Doing any form of UI manipulation in a background task or service will throw this error.